# Unable to set camera info for calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, ueye-cam, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What can be wrong if I get the following error upon camera calibration?

```
$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 4x6 --square 0.024 --approximate=0.1 --camera_name=stereo_frame right:=/right/image_raw left:=/left/image_raw right_camera:=/right left_camera:=/left

: (after seemingly successful calibration process)

Unable to set camera info for calibration. Failure message: failed to write to a file.
```

`/tmp/calibrationdata.tar.gz` is generated with .png files in it.

On the terminal where stereo camera node is launched, this error prints when I clicked on `COMMIT` button on the calibration GUI.

```
[ERROR] Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/rospasta/.ros/camera_info/left.yaml] for writing
[ERROR] Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/rospasta/.ros/camera_info/right.yaml] for writing

rosversion
1.11.10
dpkg -p ros-hydro-camera-calibration | grep Ver
1.11.10-0precise-20150101-0623-+0000
```

Btw I'm running `roslaunch nextage_ros_bridge nextage_ueye_stereo.launch` ([source](https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/blob/69ae0af97c4eace9b6ed1d2af263c4317684daf6/nextage_ros_bridge/launch/nextage_ueye_stereo.launch)) that runs [ueye_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/ueye_cam).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209058/unable-to-set-camera-info-for-calibration/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error seems to be caused by camera_calibration_parsers::writeCalibration(, , ), as seen in ueye_cam/src/ueye_cam_nodelet.cpp, UEyeCamNodelet::saveIntrinsicsFile().

I suspect that there is some write-permission issues / out-of-space issues with /home/rospasta/.ros/camera_info/. Please test and confirm.

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-07-14**:
Thanks. I no longer have an access to the same environment so can't verify but your answer gives a hint. I opened [a PR](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/pull/38) for better error message printing.